# Rescale an SVG in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have an SVG made in illustrator for an artbox of 960pt x 960pt. I'd like to insert it in a webpage of an inferior dimension.

I have tried to following to reduce it but it gets cropped like in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tjoevqo/

d3js:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', '960px')
          .attr('height', '960px');

svg.append('g').append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 480)
  .attr('cy', 480)
  .attr('r', 284.5);
```

CSS:

```
svg {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

How can I rescale it without cropping? Many thanks

Comment: You are looking for scales. I can recommend this for an introduction: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, it took me awhile to figure out what you were doing wrong. First of all `viewBox` is with a capital `B`.  So you get

```
.attr("viewBox",'0 0 1000 1000');
```

Note, I claimed it had to be with spaces rather than comma's. That's actually not the case, my bad, as per spec:

> separated by whitespace and/or a comma

It's just that spec always uses spaces...

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4tjoevqo/1/